# i' having trouble with an mp3 player

Tags: usb-drive, mp3-player

I had to replace my old mp3 player with a new 1 because of a cracked screen. The last 1 would just show up on the left side menu when i plugged it into the usb, but with this 1 nothing shows up. How do i get the system to recognize it so I can start transferring files?

Comment: All volunteers are of course psychics, that easily guess what your old and new players are ... NOT !! please update your question of all technical information, make, what you have tried, and what the results where. Also what resourcs you ave tried to follow.

Comment: Use `lsusb` (`man lsusb`), and `journalctl --follow` as you connect it. Also use an internet search engine to search your mp3 player model number " + Ubuntu"

Comment: well that man lsusb followed by journalctl did the trick. thanks a bunch.